# React - How to make input number with currency show when typing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello guys I want to make a input number but I want to show the currency while I am typing it in `input[type=number]` not `text` but it seems didn't work with `Intl.NumberFormat`. How to do that?
I want to show it like this when I am typing/focus
[image]

```js
const [lendData, setLendData] = useState({
    lendValue: 0,
    lendData: 0,
  })

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
  }
  function handleChange(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target
    setLendData((prev) => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        [name]: value,
      }
    })
  }
  
  /* Currency Format IDR */
function formatCurrency(amount) {
  return new Intl.NumberFormat('id-id', {
    currency: 'idr',
    style: 'currency',
    maximumFractionDigits: 0,
    minimumFractionDigits: 0,
  }).format(amount)
}
```

```html
<input
  type='number'
  name='lend-value'
  id='lend-value'
  placeholder='Rp 0'
  value={lendData.lendValue}
  onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

I tried to make it like this also not working

```
value={lendData.lendValue.toLocaleString('id-id', {
       style: 'currency',currency: 'idr',})}
```

it says `The specified value "Rp 0" cannot be parsed, or is out of range.`

Comment: why you dont create a text or other element to preview value from input that has been formatted?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your input name is different from the state key `lendValue != lend-value`, can you try to change the tagName to `lendValue` ?